# How can I decode a generic JSON response in Swift 4?

Tags: json, swift

I'm building an app with Swift 4 that consumes a JSON-RPC API. The responses all have the same general format:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result" : { "data_type" : [ ...a bunch of instances of data_type... ] }
    "id": 1
}
```

Where `data_type` would be `payments`, `channels`, `peers`, and so on depending on the query.

I have `Decodable` `struct` definitions for each of the data types, but I don't know how to handle the main response.

I really don't care about the `jsonrpc` or `id` fields, I'm just interested in the contents of `result`.

I tried:

```
struct LightningRPCResponse: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let result: String
    let json_rpc: String
}
```

But I got the error:

> Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead

So I tried:

```
struct LightningRPCResponse: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let result: Dictionary
    let json_rpc: String
}
```

But I got the error:

> Reference to generic type 'Dictionary' requires arguments in <...>

Is what I'm trying to do possible or do I need to create separate response decoders to correspond to every single RPC request?

Or...should I just use string manipulation to lop off the superfluous data?

Comment: `Decodable`/`Encodable` are used for structs where you know what fields you're going to have. If it's going to be generic you're better off using something like `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: `Codable` encompasses both `Decodable / Encodable`.

Comment: @GuyKogus Not true at all, you can use it for more generalized objects like `Dictionaries` without any problems.

Comment: Can you give a valid JSON example, and the definition of a couple `data_type`s?

Comment: `let result: [String, Any]`, perhaps, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make two structs:

```
struct generalStruct:Codable {
    let jsonrpc:String
    let id:Int
    let result:[resultsStruct]
}

struct resultsStruct{
     //assuming that you have strings in here, cause you didn't specify that. And it's considered as a Dictionary like: "data_tupe":"string_value" or if you have an array also here than just make another struct or just make data_type:[String]
    let data_type:String
}
```

With that structs you can decode now. Example:

```
 let json = try decoder.decode(generalStruct.self, from: response.data!)
 //here you can get access to each element of your 'data_type'
 for obj in json.result{
  for data in obj.data_type {
      //you have every element from dict access here if its more objects inside every 'data_type'
   }
 }
```